# Urturn API ur: command not found

Tags: api, node.js, expression, npm

I am trying to install urturn api and write my own expression for urturn.com
following http://webdoc.github.com/urturn-expression-api/#!guides/start

After:

```
npm install urturn-toolbelt -g
```

I am trying to run sandbox with:

```
ur sandbox
```

and got error:

```
-bash: ur: command not found
```

Please help

P.S. I am on Mac Os

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is likely your nodeJS npm/bin folder that is not included in your PATH.

Can you check your PATH variable?

Node NPM package bin files are all symlinked in the same `./bin` folder. If you installed NodeJS using Homebrew (`brew install node`), it should be `/usr/local/share/npm/bin`.

You can echo your current path using:

```
echo $PATH
```

If the folder above does not appear in the list, check your .bashrc or .bash_profile files and fix any problem.

A fix that is likely to work is to add the following line in ~/.bash_profile

`PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/share/npm/bin`